# Display sum of values dynamically entered by users in a table column

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript

Requirement is display a table should have ability to add new row and also need to display dynamic sum  of each column when user enters value with in a row column. Something like the below table. How to update total of each column value dynamically using JavaScript?

[image: mockup]

Comment: I would suggest finding a JavaScript grid component that suites your needs and then integrating that with Salesforce via e.g. JSON REST APIs. Or if you don;t need the instant response you can do quite a lot purely in Visualforce via the built in AJAX re-rendering mechanism.

Comment: would you suggest any javaScript component which supports above table features.

Comment: Not really; I would just be doing the same Googling as you...

Comment: @vraavi:can u plz share the code.I have the Similar requirement.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using Visualforce components and controller. Please note that I didn't test the code but hope you'd get the idea.

First, you create a wrapper class and a list of wrapper class in controller like:

```
class RecordObject{
    Integer Jan;
    Integer Feb;
    ...
    //put your code here   
}
List<RecordObject> recordList = new List<RecordObject>();
```

And then, you show the list on VF page using apex:inputText.

```
<apex:outputPanel id="table1">
<table ><tbody>
    <tr>
        <th>...</th> (put table headers here)
    </tr>
    <apex:repeat value="{!recordList}" var="record">
        <tr>
            <td><apex:inputText value="{!recordList.Jan}"/></td>
            <td><apex:inputText value="{!recordList.Feb}"/></td>
            .... (put all text boxes and values here)
            <td>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </apex:repeat>
</tbody></table>
</apex:outputPanel>
```

To add a row, simply put a button or a commandLink else where. Use action and rerender.

```
<apex:commandButton value="add row" action="{!addNewRow}" rerender="activityTable" />
```

In your controller. Add a record to the list. The table will be rerendered just fine.

```
public void addNewRow(){
    recordList.add(new RecordObject());
}
```

Deleting a row is trickier because controller has to know which row it'd delete. In visualforce page create a parameter called rowNum and increase its value by 1 each time through the loop used to create the table.

```
    <apex:variable value="0" var="rowNum"/>
    <apex:repeat value="{!recordList}" var="record">
       <apex:variable var="rowNum" value="{!VALUE(rowNum) + 1}"/>
    </apex:repeat>
```

Add delete button and also pass the rowNum parameter to deleteRow method in the controller.

```
    <apex:commandLink action="{!deleteRow}" value="delete" rerender="table1">
    <apex:param name="deleteRowNum" value="{!rowNum}"/>
   </apex:commandLink>

    public void deleteRow(){
    Integer deleteRowNum = Integer.ValueOf(ApexPages.CurrentPage().getParameters().get('deleteRowNum'));
        recordList.remove(deleteRowNum);
    }
```

To sum the values, You could use apex:inputText's onChange and javascript or action and rerender like above.

Comment: Thank you this solution worked. But after adding sum funtion to the table if i try to delete any row getting list out of bound exception because sum button rerender the table and also updates the variable value on VF page.

Comment: @vraavi Could you please provide the code?  :)

Comment: @IW29 it is fixed when total button rerender the VF variable.